# Android: How to draw over a single colour of a bitmap?

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap, android-canvas

I'm new to Android's 2D Graphics and I wanted to know if it is possible to do this:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6818591/pendulum_background.png

Using the image at the link above, I would like fill in the white part of the circle with a particular colour based on an angle I provide, leaving the black and transparent parts as they are.

I managed to make an arc using the `drawArc()` method but it covers the image. The problem is complicated by the fact that the arc in the image is not a perfect circle, its squashed slightly.

Is there a way to draw only on white space? Using filters or masks? If you have example code I could use that would great! :)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
private Drawable fillBitmap(Bitmap bitimg1, int r, int g, int b) {
        Bitmap bitimg = bitimg1.copy(bitimg1.getConfig(), true);


    int a = transperentframe;
    Drawable dr = null;
    for (int x = 0; x < bitimg.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < bitimg.getHeight(); y++) {

            int pixelColor = bitimg.getPixel(x, y);
            int A = Color.alpha(pixelColor);
            bitimg.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, r, g, b));
        }
    }
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitimg,
            framewidth + 10, frameheight, true);

    dr = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), resizedBitmap);

    return dr;
}
```

By using this code i filled color in non- transparent area successfully and left the transparent area as it is.

U can also check like this:

```
if(canvasBitmap.getPixel(x, y) == Color.TRANSPARENT)
```

you can compare any color Color.BLUE any apply other method according to your need.

Comment: Akanksha: Please follow this url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697189/fill-color-on-bitmap-in-android/20699644?noredirect=1#comment31008587_20699644 ... I want to integrate to fill color on image using android graphics. is it possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use `canvas.drawPaint(..)` on the bitmap to draw over a specific color with another.

```
// make a mutable copy and a canvas from this mutable bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

// get the int for the colour which needs to be removed
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0); // ARGB for the color, in this example, white
int removeColor = paint.getColor(); // store this color's int for later use

// Next, set the color of the paint to the color another color            
paint.setARGB(/*put ARGB values for color you want to change to here*/);

// then, set the Xfermode of the pain to AvoidXfermode
// removeColor is the color that will be replaced with the paint color
// 0 is the tolerance (in this case, only the color to be removed is targetted)
// Mode.TARGET means pixels with color the same as removeColor are drawn on
paint.setXfermode(new AvoidXfermode(removeColor, 0, AvoidXfermode.Mode.TARGET));

// re-draw
canvas.drawPaint(p);
```

Comment: Thanks for  the answer @James but I cant really get it to work. This is the code that i have on my onDraw method:

Bitmap bitmap = bit.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
  Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0); // ARGB for the color, in this example, white
  int removeColor = paint.getColor();
  paint.setARGB(255, 255,0,0);
  paint.setXfermode(new AvoidXfermode(removeColor, 0, AvoidXfermode.Mode.TARGET));
  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
  canvas.drawPaint(paint);

What I get is just a red screen.

Comment: You need to modify the `paint.setARGB(255,0,0,0)` line to match the ARGB values of the color you want to overlay.