# Fill color on bitmap in android

Tags: android, seekbar, flood-fill

How i can fill color on image(i.e fuel image) in specific area as per Seek bar progress.

i have tried following solution but it is not helpful much as per my requirement.

please find below image for more reference.

[image]

Comment: Assuming you are trying to fill the "Gas Meter" as the progressBar increases, you could create multiple images showing different levels and replace images as needed. Use an AsyncTask and change the images in the onProgressUpdate method. Everytime you call publish() it will read progress and adjust bar and images accordingly

Comment: Thanks for giving me replay. i need 100 images as per your solution which is not feasible for me.

Comment: I know you can use PorterDuffMode to color an entire image view, but I'm unsure how to do it for say half of an image. I worked on a custom ROM that had a circle style battery that allowed color changing and it was all done programitacally. Here's a link to that code [link](https://github.com/TeamSourcery/frameworks_base/blob/jb4.2.2/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/policy/CircleBattery.java)

Answer (score 1):

You could also draw a bitmap on top of the layer you have.
Simply add a bitmap with the same dimensions as the bar (or whatever you have) you want to have coloured in. Then add the colours and say how far it should colour in the bar.

Example:

```
// making our bitmap and canvas
        Bitmap bmResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(barWidth, 75,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmResult);
        paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(widthToFill, 75, widthToFill, 75,
                0xFF97ca3e, 0xFF284060, TileMode.MIRROR));
        paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(widthToFill, 75, widthToFill, 75,
                0xFF97ca3e, 0xFF284060, TileMode.CLAMP));
        paint.setARGB(188, 164, 120, 130);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, widthToFill, 75, paint);
```

widthToFill would be a variable with the value of how much you want to draw in. You could also draw this dynamic by getting the screenwidth and calculating the percentages.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for giving me replay, Let me try this one.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you've got this working and if you need more info just leave a post. Oh and if it did the deal, please accept my answer!

Comment: Yenthe : We got your point but we need to fill color on image. Please see above image (i.e. Fuel Tank). When user slid seek bar manually, we need to fill pink color on image (ie fuel tank) right side of seek bar. Did you get my point?

Comment: Ahh I thought you were referring to the blue bar (and how far it should be coloured in blue / gray) Well if you are talking about the tank, that is also possible with the paint.. but I have no idea how to exactly draw in that shape. Since it has a lot of corners etc.. My method works easily for rectangles, squares etc but I haven't tested it out on such a shapes yet. You could either choose for changing your image to something square / rectangle / ... or you'll need to figure out how to get all the x and y axes and draw them in. Good luck!

Comment: 2 calls to setShader wont add the second, but overwrite the first one